# Iterate through a list of dictionaries and save duplicate data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to iterate through a list of dictionaries and save values of certain keys (in my case "consumer Key" and "consumer Secret") as many times they are present into another dictionary.

Problem: I'm able to iterate through the list but my code is not saving the second consumer key and consumer secret, instead it is saving the first consumer key and consumer secret twice.

Input:

```
{
    "accessType": "",
    "apiProducts": [],
    "appFamily": "default",
    "appId": "ac56c8b2-6ac1-4971-a1d3-4bf97893c067",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "DisplayName",
            "value": "quotaapp"
        },
        {
            "name": "Notes",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "callbackUrl": "",
    "createdAt": 1549274952045,
    "createdBy": "suraj.pai.airody@sap.com",
    "credentials": [
        {
            "apiProducts": [
                {
                    "apiproduct": "apiprod",
                    "status": "approved"
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [],
            "consumerKey": "xyz",
            "consumerSecret": "abc",
            "expiresAt": -1,
            "issuedAt": 1549274952051,
            "scopes": [],
            "status": "approved"
        },
        {
            "apiProducts": [
                {
                    "apiproduct": "ouathTest-Product",
                    "status": "approved"
                }
            ],
            "attributes": [],
            "consumerKey": "pqr",
            "consumerSecret": "wmn",
            "expiresAt": -1,
            "issuedAt": 1554802431452,
            "scopes": [],
            "status": "approved"
        }
    ],
    "developerId": "xyz",
    "lastModifiedAt": 1554802431662,
    "lastModifiedBy": "suraj.pai.airody@sap.com",
    "name": "quotaapp",
    "scopes": [],
    "status": "approved"
}
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import csv


def get_v2details():
    a = 'orgID1'
    b = 'appID1'
    c = 'ConKey1'
    d = 'ConSecret1'
    e = 'appName1'
    org_lst = []
    some_dict = {}
    con_blst = []  # variable to append the dictionary app level
    n = int(input("Enter number of orgs from Landscape 1: "))
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = str(input())
        org_lst.append(ele)
    cmp_orglst = list(org_lst)
    print(cmp_orglst)
    for j in cmp_orglst:
        url = "https://canarydevmgmtsrv.dmzmo.sap.corp/v1/o/" + str(j) + "/apps/"
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xyz', 'xyz'), headers=headers, verify=False)
        app_data = json.loads(response.text)
        print(app_data)
        for k in app_data:
            url1 = "https://canarydevmgmtsrv.dmzmo.sap.corp/v1/o/" + str(j) + "/apps/" + str(k)
            headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            response1 = requests.get(url1, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xyz', 'xyz'), headers=headers, verify=False)
            consumer_data = json.loads(response1.text)
            print(" Consumer Data is ", consumer_data)
            for l in range(len(consumer_data['credentials'])):
                some_dict[a] = str(j)
                some_dict[b] = consumer_data['appId']
                some_dict[e] = consumer_data['name']
                some_dict[c] = consumer_data['credentials'][0]['consumerKey']
                some_dict[d] = consumer_data['credentials'][0]['consumerSecret']
                print(some_dict)  # Print dictionary of each app ID
                con_blst.append(some_dict.copy())
            print(con_blst)

            csv_columns = ['orgID1', 'appName1', 'appID1', 'ConKey1', 'ConSecret1']
            csv_file = "Names1.csv"
            try:
                with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
                    writer.writeheader()
                    for data in con_blst:
                        writer.writerow(data)
            except IOError:
                print("I/O error")
```

Expected result:

```
orgID1         appName1         appID1         ConKey1      ConSecret1
VALIDATE    quotaapp    4bf97893c067   xyz           abc
VALIDATE    quotaapp        4bf97893c067    pqr          wmn
```

Actual result:

```
orgID1         appName1         appID1         ConKey1      ConSecret1
VALIDATE    quotaapp    4bf97893c067   xyz           abc
VALIDATE    quotaapp        4bf97893c067    xyz          abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just made a small error.

```
        for l in range(len(consumer_data['credentials'])):
            some_dict[a] = str(j)
            some_dict[b] = consumer_data['appId']
            some_dict[e] = consumer_data['name']
            some_dict[c] = consumer_data['credentials'][0]['consumerKey']   #this line
            some_dict[d] = consumer_data['credentials'][0]['consumerSecret'] #and this line
            print(some_dict)  # Print dictionary of each app ID
            con_blst.append(some_dict.copy())
```

Should be

```
        for l in range(len(consumer_data['credentials'])):
            some_dict[a] = str(j)
            some_dict[b] = consumer_data['appId']
            some_dict[e] = consumer_data['name']
            some_dict[c] = consumer_data['credentials'][l]['consumerKey']    # Here
            some_dict[d] = consumer_data['credentials'][l]['consumerSecret'] # Here
            print(some_dict)  # Print dictionary of each app ID
            con_blst.append(some_dict.copy())
```

You weren't looping through `consumer_data['credentials']`, you were just storing `consumer_data['credentials'][0]` twice

Comment: Getting error:     some_dict[c] = consumer_data['credentials'][1]['consumerKey']
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Just a sanity check, you put in the letter `l` instead of the number `1` right?

Comment: You are right, I had put numeric one instead of letter lowercase "L". Now the code is working perfect.